# What manga is this picture of a couple kissing from?

Tags: identification-request

[image: couple kiss]

What manga is this image from? I found it on Tumblr, but I couldn't find the name of the manga.

Comment: My bet is that this is from a hentai manga, one that is published in hentai manga magazine.

Comment: @nhahtdh: the original post for this that I found on Tumblr seemed to be on a blog focused on ecchi, so I really wouldn't be surprised at all.

Answer (score 3):

It's from a hentai manga by `Otsuka Kotora`. The tankoubon title is `Angraecum`. The story title is `Phalaenopsis`. It's the third story in the tankoubon.

[image]

[image]